# Sublime Text find and replace "foo" across all situations and combinations except when it becomes another word ie. "foobar"

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

I know this is a elementary RegEx possibility, but I can't seem to determine the right expression to use.

What I am looking to do is find & replace "foo" and only "foo" within a set of different situations like; abc_foo, abc_foo[something], abc-foo-something, and all different combinations except when it becomes another word like "foobar". The basic 'whole word' search function was close but doesn't help when variables and underscores are factored in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not that elementary to match a string which does not contain word characters around itself:

If your language supports [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is quite rare occasion, it would be simple:

```
(?<!\w)foo(?!\w)
```

However, there is a workaround to match the string with surrounding non-word characters (including `_` which is a word character but you want to treat is as non-word) and use capturing groups to sort it all out:

```
(^|[\W_])foo([\W_]|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3vYo7VNo7u_YGbc8)

e.g. in javascript syntax:

```
str.replace(/(^|[\W_])foo([\W_]|$)/g, "$1replacement$2");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! You're the man, thanks!

slight off topic: is the $1 and $2 telling the engine to keep the character before and after the replacement untouched?

Comment: in this case, yes, but in general it's the whole content of capturing groups 1 an 2, not just single characters..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion to do this.  Using regex search, `foo(?!bar)` will match any instance of foo not followed by bar, and the following text is not part of the match, only foo is.